# How does one sanctify meat for consumption?

Tags: mahabharata, manu-smriti

There is a popular misconception among Hindus that jhatka meat is fit for consumption (apparently it is quick death for the animal). While it maybe true in Sikhism, I have not come across anything from hindu scriptures to support it.

Now Manusmriti and Mahabharata say that sanctified is pure

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b080.htm

> Mann himself has said that meat which is sanctified with mantras and properly dedicated, according to the ordinances of the Vedas, in rites performed in honour of the Pitris, is pure.

Can someone provide links to these mantras ? Most helpful if they can be categorized - before eating, before cooking, before eating etc.

P.S. - by meat i am not referring to beef. I am referring to poultry, goat etc

Comment: There is an elaborate Tantriki procedure of sanctifying meat. At first the animal is given a bath, followed by the sprinkling of water with kusha grass over it's body accompanied by the recitation of specific Vaidika mantras. Then each body part of the animal is assigned to a specific deity. Then the sacrificial sword is worshipped. Kalaratri (the deity presiding over unnatural death) is invoked in that sword accompanied by the worship of the sacrificial post. The animal is then gifted to the main deity & slaughtered with the sanctified sword in one blow.

Comment: @AnubrataBit - Thank you. Can you pls point out these vaidika mantras ?

Comment: अग्निः पशुरासीत् । तेनायजन्त स एतं लोकमजयद्यस्मिन्नग्निः स ते लोको भविष्यति तं जेष्यसि पिबैता अप ।। वायुः पशुरासीत्  ।तेनायजन्त स एतं लोकमजयद्यस्मिन्वायुः स ते लोको भविष्यति तं जेष्यसि पिबैता अप ।। सूर्यः पशुरासीत् । तेनायजन्त स एतं लोकमजयद्यस्मिन्त्सूर्यः स ते लोको भविष्यति
तं जेष्यसि पिबैता अप ।। [Shatapatha Brahmana:13th kanda:2nd adhyaya:7th brahmana]

Comment: Srividyarnavatantra includes some additional mantras for prokshana like the Panchabrahma mantras, आपो हिष्ठा मयोभुव ..., हंस शुचिषत् ..., वरुणस्योत्तम्भनमसि ...., विष्णुः पशुरासीत् ..., रुद्रः पशुरासीत् ...., & the Gayatri mantra.

Comment: However Devi Bhagavata Purana states that even eating sanctified meat for tongue satiation amounts to sin. Brahmavaivarta Purana identifies buffalo, sheep & goat as the only legitimate sources of meat fit for human consumption.

Comment: @AnubrataBit - This is helpful. Can you compile it into an answer ? And which section of Brahmavaivarta Purana and Devi Bhagavata Purana has this been mentioned?

Comment: The mantras given in scriptures are for purifying meat when meat is being used for some rituals not for personal consumption ....

Comment: Just purifying the meat/food is not enough .. it has to be duly sacrificed/dedicated to some deity .. these are all part of rituals and can't be done without learning all the details from Guru .. even the quote in Q says "sanctified with mantras and **properly dedicated**" .. so it has to be sanctified and dedicated not just sanctified.

Comment: @Rickross - Indeed. But as you are aware that animal sacrifices in temples has been increasingly clamped down by Indian govt over the years. Just today few were arrested for sacrificing chicken at a temple in Kerala. So are there any remedies provided in scriptures in such scenario ?

Comment: It is largely not possible unless one has a home temple. @Carmensandiego

Comment: @Rickross - i read somewhere that there are birthmarks on animals by which you can determine that there are fit for bali. Are you aware on the treatise that talks about it? Apparently animals that have such birthmarks not only obtained higher realms but also don't show any resistance when being led to the altar for sacrifice

Comment: @Carmensandiego I don't know about such birth marks on animals but I have asked a Q about something very closely related to what you're saying here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22082/4732.

Comment: @Rickross - ahh. Pretty much the same question. Will try hard to look it up

Comment: Udaranimittam bahukṛtavēṣāḥ. The whole point of animal sacrifice is to quench meat eaters. People who could not give up meat imagined up all these different mantras and stories to justify their lack of austerity.

Comment: @AravindSuresh Read the portion of the Devibhagavatam quoted here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52610/is-it-valid-to-quote-half-lines-of-%c5%9blokas